# MVC pattern: to a controller can correspond more views or only one

Tags: php, model-view-controller, codeigniter, design-patterns

I'm studying MVC pattern applying it to codeigniter and I have a doubt: to any controller can correspond only and only one view or more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out:

[Displaying Multiple Views](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Displaying_Multiple_Views/)

This means, a controller can display one or more views depending on how you construct your views.